# How to add 3 column in 1 layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

first of all, sorry for my poor English.
I want to design a layout. If you look at the picture below you will understand what I am saying. In the second line, columns are dispersed.

I got this:

```
User   User  User
User User  User
User    User    User
```

I need:

```
User User User
User User User
```

- [Actual layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEXNf.png)
- [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0evn.png)

  ```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="TEST1"
      android:id="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      style="@style/diziKanalsüreTextViews" />

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="TEST2"
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      style="@style/diziKanalsüreTextViews" />

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="TEST3"
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      style="@style/diziKanalsüreTextViews" />
  ```

  ```
  <TableRow
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:text="Micheal Jackson"
          android:id="@+id/textView8"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:text="YEAR 2016"
          android:id="@+id/textView9"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:text="New York City"
          android:id="@+id/textView10"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1" />
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:text="Muhammad Ali"
          android:id="@+id/textView5"
          android:layout_weight="0.45" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:text="3241"
          android:id="@+id/textView6"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:text="Londra"
          android:id="@+id/textView7"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1" />
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:id="@+id/textView11"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="Serena Williams" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:text="Text Here.ETC"
          android:id="@+id/textView12"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
          android:text="Istanbul"
          android:id="@+id/textView13"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1" />
  </TableRow>
  ```

Comment: set TableRow weight to 1 and it's children to 0.33

Comment: Changing your `LinearLayout` which wraps around your `TableRow`s into a `TableLayout` should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set layout_width="0dp" if you want to use layout_weight. 
Your layout xml can be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TEST1 asdjfga sdfa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TEST2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TEST3" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView42"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TEST1 asdjfga sdfa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView32"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TEST2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TEST3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Test"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Test"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Test"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Test"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Test"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Test"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Use `TableLayout`, not `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use RecyclerView and set GridLayout as LayoutManager?